# How to build Botframework-WebChat v4

Tags: botframework, web-chat

Sorry for asking this, but how can i build the [botframework-webchat v4.5.2](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/v4.5.2)? I ran 'npm run bootstrap' and 'npm run build'. Both commands exited successfully, but i can't find the webchat.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `npm run build:sample` when you are first getting started. Then the normal build and watch commands should build the webchat.js files from then on. Not sure if this is documented anywhere.

```sh
npm install
npm run bootstrap
npm run build:sample

npm run build
```

To run the test harness run `npm run start:docker` and wait for the command to finish - it should take awhile for docker container to build. Then in another terminal run `npm test`.

Hope this helps!